# How to create a quad, which is visible from both sides?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'm working with face culling enabled, but I would like to make some quads visible from both sides. How is it possible, without using two quads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of such objects are smaller compared to the others, you can repeat drawing the other side with the opposite winding order but with the same texture, so that it appears on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to disable backface culling using:

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Read up on face culling here: [Face Culling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling)

**Edit**

If you can't disable Face Culling, then you could possible do some **crazy** black magic where you `dot()` a view normal against the polygon normal and, depending on the result, switch the wind order with `glFrontFace()`.  However, this is **incredibly** inefficient compared to just drawing the quad twice.  Other than that, I am unaware of a way to do it.

Comment: But I have to leave enabled the face culling

Comment: Create double sided triangles then.. but you say you don't want to do that so actually, no its not possible AFAIK.

Comment: @IterAtor I really don't know another way to do it other than a zany cludge.  Maybe someone else will know.  Why do you have to leave it enabled?